# Email is extending past the 600px width in all Outlook clients

Tags: css, email, outlook, html-email

ANY help will do! I have been doing this email testing for hours now. I have been researching and all! I can't seem to figure out why my email is not obeying the width of 600. Here is my code below and a screenshot of what I am seeing on Email on Acid testing platform. My email looks great on literally every other email client except all the Outlooks. Only Outlook it looks good on is Outlook 2003 Windows 7. I can't google anymore on why Outlook sucks with email development! Please any advice and help will do!

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

```
    <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<!-- If you delete this tag, the sky will fall on your head -->
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
<title>All-Wall Abandoned Cart Email</title>    
  <!--[if gte mso 7]><xml>
  <o:OfficeDocumentSettings>
  <o:AllowPNG/>
  <o:PixelsPerInch>96</o:PixelsPerInch>
  </o:OfficeDocumentSettings>
    </xml><![endif]-->
  <style type="text/css">
    * { 
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
        font-family: "Helvetica Neue", "Helvetica", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
        box-sizing: border-box;
    }

    body {
        -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased; 
        -webkit-text-size-adjust: none; 
        width: 100% !important; 
        height: 100%;
        color: #000;
    }

    img { 
        max-width: 100%; 
        display: block;
        border: 0;
        outline: 0;
    }

    .collapse {
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
    }

    .container {
        display: block !important;
        max-width: 600px !important;
        margin: 0 auto !important; 
        clear: both !important;
        background-color: #FFF;
    }

    .content {
        max-width: 600px;
        margin: 0 auto;
        display: block; 
    }

    .content table, .content table tr, .content table tr td  { 
        max-width: 100%; 
        border-collapse: collapse;
        border: 0;
        outline: 0;
        border-spacing: 0;
    }

    table {
        width: 100%;
        display: table;
    }

    .two-col table {
        width: 300px;

    }

    .three-col table {
        width: 200px;
    }

    .pad--left {
            padding-left: 25px;
        }

    @media only screen and (max-width: 480px) {

        .two-col table, .three-col table {
            width: 100%; 
        }
        .pad--left {
            padding-left: 100px;
        }

    }
</style>
</head>

<body bgcolor="#ccc">
<table role="presentation" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
 <!--[if mso]>
 <center>
 <table><tr><td width="580">
<![endif]-->
    <tr>
        <td>
            <!-- HEADER -->
            <table role="presentation" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
                <tr>
                    <td></td>
                    <td class="container">
                        <div class="content">
                            <table role="presentation" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
                                <tr>
                                    <td style="padding-top: 15px; padding-bottom: 15px; padding-left: 15px; padding-right: 5px;">
                                        <!--[if mso]>
                                <table role="presentation" width="50%"><tr><td><img width="45" src="http://hosting-source.bm23.com/35348/public/Pictures/2020_Abandoned_Cart_Images/phone-icon.png" alt="phone icon" style="text-align: right; width: 45px; border: 0; text-decoration:none; vertical-align: baseline;"></td></tr></table>
                                <div style="display:none">
                                    <![endif]-->
                                        <img style="display:block;" src="http://hosting-source.bm23.com/35348/public/Pictures/2020_Abandoned_Cart_Images/phone-icon.png" alt="phone icon" style="width: 45px;"/ />
                                        <!--[if mso]>
                                        </div>
                                        <![endif]-->
                                      </td>
                                    <td style="padding-top: 15px; padding-bottom: 15px; padding-left: 5px; padding-right: 5px;">
                                        <span style="font-weight: bold; color: #0067B9;">Need Help? Se habla español</span> 
                                        <br> 
                                        <a href="tel:8009290927" style="color: #000; text-decoration: none;">(800) 929-0927</a>
                                    </td>
                                    <td style="padding-top: 15px; padding-bottom: 15px; padding-left: 5px; padding-right: 15px;" align="right">
                                        View email as <a href="%%!preview_url%% " style="font-weight: bold; color: #0067B9; text-decoration: none;">webpage</a>
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                            </table>
                        </div>  
                    </td>
                    <td></td>
                </tr>
            </table><!-- /HEADER -->

            <!-- BODY -->
            <table role="presentation" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
                <tr>
                    <td></td>
                    <td class="container">
                        <div class="content">
                            <table role="presentation" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
                                <tr>
                                    <td align="center" style="padding-top: 15px; padding-bottom: 45px;">
                                        <!--[if mso]>
                                <table role="presentation" width="50%"><tr><td><img width="243" src="http://hosting-source.bm23.com/35348/public/Pictures/2020_Abandoned_Cart_Images/All-Wall-LogoBanner.png" alt="cart image" style="text-align: right; width: 243px; border: 0; text-decoration:none; vertical-align: baseline;"></td></tr></table>
                                <div style="display:none">
                                    <![endif]-->
                                    <img style="display:block;" src="http://hosting-source.bm23.com/35348/public/Pictures/2020_Abandoned_Cart_Images/All-Wall-LogoBanner.png" alt="logo" />
                                    <!--[if mso]>
                                    </div>
                                    <![endif]-->
                                  </td>  
                                </tr>
                            </table>
                            <table role="presentation" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
                                <tr>
                                    <td align="center"> 
                                        <table role="presentation" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" style="background-image: linear-gradient(to right, #EFEFEF , #FFF); background-color: #EFEFEF;">
                                            <tr>
                                                <td align="center" style="padding-top: 40px;">
                                                    <img style="display:block;" src="http://hosting-source.bm23.com/35348/public/Pictures/2020_Abandoned_Cart_Images/cart-icon.png" alt="cart icon" />
                                                </td>
                                            </tr>
                                            <tr>
                                                <td align="center">
                                                    <h3 style="display: inline-block; font-weight: 400; font-size: 25px; padding-top: 5px; padding-bottom: 25px;">We've Saved Your Cart</h3>
                                                    <!--[if mso]>
                                            <table role="presentation" width="50%"><tr><td><img width="30" src="http://hosting-source.bm23.com/35348/public/Pictures/2020_Abandoned_Cart_Images/cart.png" alt="cart image" style="text-align: right; width: 30px; border: 0; text-decoration:none; vertical-align: baseline;"></td></tr></table>
                                            <div style="display:none">
                                                <![endif]-->
                          <img src="http://hosting-source.bm23.com/35348/public/Pictures/2020_Abandoned_Cart_Images/cart.png" alt="cart image" style="width:30px; display: inline-block;" />
                                                    <!--[if mso]>
                          </div>
                            <![endif]-->
                        </td>
                                            </tr>
                                            <tr>
                                                <td align="center" style="padding-bottom: 25px;">
                          <a href="#" style="text-decoration: none; display: inline-block;"><span style="background-color: #FFF; padding-top: 10px; padding-bottom: 10px; padding-left: 20px; padding-right: 20px; border: 2px solid #B30F11; color: #B30F11; font-weight: 500; display: block; margin-left: 10px; margin-bottom: 10px; margin-right: 10px; margin-right: 10px; font-size: 18px;">Shop Now</span></a>
                                                    <a href="#" style="text-decoration: none; display: inline-block;"><span style="background-color: #FFF; padding-top: 10px; padding-bottom: 10px; padding-left: 20px; padding-right: 20px; border: 2px solid #B30F11; color: #B30F11; font-weight: 500; display: block; margin-left: 10px; margin-bottom: 10px; margin-right: 10px; margin-right: 10px; font-size: 18px;">View Cart</span></a>
                                                </td>
                                            </tr>
                                        </table>
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                            </table>
                            <table role="presentation" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
                                <tr>
                                    <td align="center" style=" background-color: #EFEFEF; background-image: url(http://hosting-source.bm23.com/35348/public/Pictures/2020_Abandoned_Cart_Images/worker-bg.png); background-repeat: no-repeat; background-size: cover; background-position: right; padding-top: 45px; padding-bottom: 85px; padding-left: 0; padding-right: 0; margin-left: 0; margin-right: 0; border: 0; color: #FFF; text-transform: uppercase; width: 100%;">
                                        <h2 style="color: #FFF; text-transform: uppercase; font-size: 40px; padding-bottom: 15px;">Hurry while It&#8217;s<br>still in stock</h2>
                                        <a href="#" style="text-decoration: none;"><span style="color: #FFF; text-transform: uppercase; font-size: 16px; font-weight: 600; display: block;">Return to your cart</span></a>
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                            </table>
                            <table role="presentation" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
                                <tr>
                                    <td class="three-col" style="padding-top: 15px; padding-bottom: 15px; background-color: #00549A; color: #FFF; text-transform: uppercase;">
                                        <!--[if mso]>
                                <table role="presentation" width="33%"><tr><td></td></tr></table>
                                <div style="display:none">
                                    <![endif]-->    
                    <table role="presentation" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" style="display: inline-block;">
                                                <tbody>
                                                    <tr>
                                                        <td align="center" style="padding-left: 25px;">
                              <!--[if mso]>
                                                    <table role="presentation" width="50%"><tr><td><img width="48" src="http://hosting-source.bm23.com/35348/public/Pictures/2020_Abandoned_Cart_Images/satisfaction.png" alt="satisfaction icon" style="text-align: right; width: 48px; border: 0; text-decoration:none; vertical-align: baseline;"></td></tr></table>
                                                    <div style="display:none">
                                                        <![endif]-->
                              <img src="http://hosting-source.bm23.com/35348/public/Pictures/2020_Abandoned_Cart_Images/satisfaction.png" alt="satisfaction icon" style="padding: 5px; display: block;" /></td>
                                                            <!--[if mso]>
                                </div>
                                    <![endif]-->
                            <td align="left" style="color: #FFF; text-transform: uppercase;">Satisfaction<br>Guarantee</td>
                                                    </tr>
                                            </tbody>
                                            </table><!--[if mso]>
                                </div>
                                    <![endif]--><!--[if mso]>
                                <table role="presentation" width="33%"><tr><td></td></tr></table>
                                <div style="display:none">
                                    <![endif]--><table role="presentation" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" style="display: inline-block;">
                                                <tbody>
                                                    <tr>
                                                        <td align="center" style="padding-left: 25px;">
                              <!--[if mso]>
                                                    <table role="presentation" width="50%"><tr><td><img width="48" src="http://hosting-source.bm23.com/35348/public/Pictures/2020_Abandoned_Cart_Images/fastship.png" alt="fast ship icon" style="text-align: right; width: 48px; border: 0; text-decoration:none; vertical-align: baseline;"></td></tr></table>
                                                    <div style="display:none">
                                                        <![endif]-->
                              <img src="http://hosting-source.bm23.com/35348/public/Pictures/2020_Abandoned_Cart_Images/fastship.png" alt="fast ship icon" style="padding: 5px; display: block;" /></td>
                                                            <!--[if mso]>
                                </div>
                                    <![endif]-->
                            <td align="left" style="color: #FFF; text-transform: uppercase;">Fast<br>Shipping</td>
                                                    </tr>
                                                </tbody>
                                            </table><!--[if mso]>
                                </div>
                                    <![endif]--><table role="presentation" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" style="display: inline-block;">
                                                <tbody>
                                                    <tr>
                                                        <td align="center" style="padding-left: 25px;">
                              <!--[if mso]>
                                                    <table role="presentation" width="50%"><tr><td><img width="48" src="http://hosting-source.bm23.com/35348/public/Pictures/2020_Abandoned_Cart_Images/freeship.png" alt="free ship icon" style="text-align: right; width: 48px; border: 0; text-decoration:none; vertical-align: baseline;"></td></tr></table>
                                                    <div style="display:none">
                                                        <![endif]-->
                              <img src="http://hosting-source.bm23.com/35348/public/Pictures/2020_Abandoned_Cart_Images/freeship.png" alt="free ship icon" style="padding: 5px; display: block;" /></td>
                                                            <!--[if mso]>
                                </div>
                                    <![endif]-->
                            <td align="left" style="color: #FFF; text-transform: uppercase;">Many items<br>Ship free</td>
                                                    </tr>
                                                </tbody>
                                            </table>        
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                            </table>
                            <table role="presentation" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
                                <tr>
                                    <td align="center" style="padding-top: 65px; padding-bottom: 5px;padding-left: 15px; padding-right: 15px;">
                                        <h3 style="font-size: 25px; text-transform: uppercase;">Customer Reviews</h3>
                                        <hr style="margin: 15px 0;">
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                            </table>
                            <table role="presentation" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
                                <tr>
                                    <td style="padding-left: 35px; padding-right: 35px; padding-bottom: 15px; text-align: center;">
                                        <table role="presentation" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" style="width: 100%;">
                                            <tr>
                                                <td align="right" valign="bottom" style="vertical-align:top; font-size: 14px; font-weight: bold; display: inline-block; margin-right: 10px; padding-top: 5px;">Excellent</td>
                                                <td align="center" valign="top" style="vertical-align:top; display: inline-block;margin-top: -3px;">
                                                    <!--[if mso]>
                                            <table role="presentation" width="50%"><tr><td><img width="100" src="http://hosting-source.bm23.com/35348/public/Pictures/2020_Abandoned_Cart_Images/five-stars.png" alt="five stars" style="text-align: right; width: 100px; border: 0; text-decoration:none; vertical-align: baseline;"></td></tr></table>
                                            <div style="display:none">
                                                <![endif]-->
                          <img src="http://hosting-source.bm23.com/35348/public/Pictures/2020_Abandoned_Cart_Images/five-stars.png" alt="five stars" style="padding: 1px; width: 100px; display: inline-block; padding-top: 5px;" />
                                                    <!--[if mso]>
                          </div>
                            <![endif]-->
                        </td>
                                                <td align="right" style="font-size: 12px; display: inline-block; padding-top: 5px;">1,880 reviews on&nbsp;</td>
                                                <td align="center" style="display: inline-block; padding-top: 5px;">
                                                    <!--[if mso]>
                                            <table role="presentation" width="50%"><tr><td><img width="20" src="http://hosting-source.bm23.com/35348/public/Pictures/2020_Abandoned_Cart_Images/star.png" alt="five stars" style="text-align: right; width: 20px; border: 0; text-decoration:none; vertical-align: baseline;"></td></tr></table>
                                            <div style="display:none">
                                                <![endif]-->
                          <img src="http://hosting-source.bm23.com/35348/public/Pictures/2020_Abandoned_Cart_Images/star.png" alt="star icon" style="padding: 1px; width: 20px; display: inline-block; margin-top: -7px; padding-top: 5px;" />
                                                    <!--[if mso]>
                          </div>
                            <![endif]-->
                        </td>
                                                <td align="left" style="font-size: 12px; display: inline-block; padding-top: 5px;">&nbsp;Trustpilot</td>
                                            </tr>
                                        </table>
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                            </table>
                            <table>
                                <tr>
                                    <td style="padding-left: 45px; padding-right: 45px; padding-bottom: 35px;">
                                        <table role="presentation" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
                                            <tr>
                                                <td style="font-size: 12px; padding-top: 25px; color: #707070;">
                                                    Brain Merryman &#8226;  2 reviews
                                                    <hr style="margin: 15px 0;">
                                                </td>
                                            </tr>
                                            <tr>
                                                <td>
                                                    <table role="presentation" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" style="width: 100%;">
                                                        <tr>
                                                            <td style="width: 115px;">
                                                                <!--[if mso]>
                                                        <table role="presentation" width="50%"><tr><td><img width="100" src="http://hosting-source.bm23.com/35348/public/Pictures/2020_Abandoned_Cart_Images/five-stars.png" alt="five stars" style="text-align: right; width: 100px; border: 0; text-decoration:none; vertical-align: baseline;"></td></tr></table>
                                                        <div style="display:none">
                                                            <![endif]-->
                                <img src="http://hosting-source.bm23.com/35348/public/Pictures/2020_Abandoned_Cart_Images/five-stars.png" alt="five stars" style="padding: 1px; width: 100px;" />    
                                                                <!--[if mso]>
                                </div>
                                <![endif]-->
                              </td>
                                                            <td style="width: 20px;">
                                                                <!--[if mso]>
                                <table role="presentation" width="50%"><tr><td><img width="16" src="http://hosting-source.bm23.com/35348/public/Pictures/2020_Abandoned_Cart_Images/check.png" alt="checkmark" style="text-align: right; width: 16px; border: 0; text-decoration:none; vertical-align: baseline;"></td></tr></table>
                                <div style="display:none">
                                <![endif]-->
                                <img src="http://hosting-source.bm23.com/35348/public/Pictures/2020_Abandoned_Cart_Images/check.png" alt="checkmark" style="padding: 1px; width: 16px; " />
                                                                <!--[if mso]>
                                </div>
                                 <![endif]-->
                              </td>
                                                            <td style="font-size: 12px; color: #707070;">
                                                                <span>Verified</span>
                                                            </td>
                                                        </tr>
                                                    </table>
                                                </td>
                                            </tr>
                                            <tr>
                                                <td style="padding-top: 25px; padding-bottom: 25px;">
                                                    <h3 style="padding-bottom: 10px;">Had an awesome experience</h3>
                                                    <span style="font-size:14px; line-height: 22px;">Had an awesome experience. Product was great and shipping was fast</span>
                                                </td>
                                            </tr>
                                        </table>
                                        <table role="presentation" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
                                            <tr>
                                                <td style="font-size: 12px; padding-top: 25px; color: #707070;">
                                                    Jeff &#8226;  1 review
                                                    <hr style="margin: 15px 0;">
                                                </td>
                                            </tr>
                                            <tr>
                                                <td>
                                                    <table role="presentation" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" style="width: 100%;">
                                                        <tr>
                                                            <td style="width: 115px;">
                                                                <!--[if mso]>
                                                        <table role="presentation" width="50%"><tr><td><img width="100" src="http://hosting-source.bm23.com/35348/public/Pictures/2020_Abandoned_Cart_Images/five-stars.png" alt="five stars" style="text-align: right; width: 100px; border: 0; text-decoration:none; vertical-align: baseline;"></td></tr></table>
                                                        <div style="display:none">
                                                            <![endif]-->
                                <img src="http://hosting-source.bm23.com/35348/public/Pictures/2020_Abandoned_Cart_Images/five-stars.png" alt="five stars" style="padding: 1px; width: 100px;" />    
                                                                <!--[if mso]>
                                </div>
                                <![endif]-->
                              </td>
                                                            <td style="width: 20px;">
                                                                <!--[if mso]>
                                <table role="presentation" width="50%"><tr><td><img width="16" src="http://hosting-source.bm23.com/35348/public/Pictures/2020_Abandoned_Cart_Images/check.png" alt="checkmark" style="text-align: right; width: 16px; border: 0; text-decoration:none; vertical-align: baseline;"></td></tr></table>
                                <div style="display:none">
                                <![endif]-->
                                <img src="http://hosting-source.bm23.com/35348/public/Pictures/2020_Abandoned_Cart_Images/check.png" alt="checkmark" style="padding: 1px; width: 16px; " />
                                                                <!--[if mso]>
                                </div>
                                 <![endif]-->
                              </td>
                                                            <td style="font-size: 12px; color: #707070;">
                                                                <span>Verified</span>
                                                            </td>
                                                        </tr>
                                                    </table>
                                                </td>
                                            </tr>
                                            <tr>
                                                <td style="padding-top: 25px; padding-bottom: 25px;">
                                                    <h3 style="padding-bottom: 10px;">Fast accurate order fulfillment.</h3>
                                                    <span style="font-size:14px; line-height: 22px;">Fast accurate order fulfillment. Very happy with All-Wall Equipment!!</span>
                                                </td>
                                            </tr>
                                        </table>
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                            </table>
                            <table role="presentation" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
                                <tr>
                                    <td class="two-col" style=" background-color: #EFEFEF; background-image: url(http://hosting-source.bm23.com/35348/public/Pictures/2020_Abandoned_Cart_Images/support-bg.png); background-repeat: no-repeat; background-size: cover; padding-top: 85px; padding-bottom: 85px; padding-left: 25px; padding-right: 25px;">
                                        <table role="presentation" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
                                            <tr>
                                                <td align="center">
                                                    <img src="http://hosting-source.bm23.com/35348/public/Pictures/2020_Abandoned_Cart_Images/phone.png" alt="phone" style="padding: 1px; width: 30px;" />  
                                                </td>
                                            </tr>
                                            <tr>
                                                <td align="center" style="font-size: 30px;">
                                                    Customer Support
                                                </td>
                                            </tr>
                                            <tr>
                                                <td align="center" style=" padding-top: 10px; padding-bottom: 10px;">
                                                    <a href="tel:8009290927" style="color: #0067B9; font-size: 36px; font-weight: bold; text-decoration: none;">(800) 929-0927</a>
                                                </td>
                                            </tr>
                                            <tr>
                                                <td align="center" style="font-size: 16px; font-weight: bold; text-decoration: underline;">
                                                    Se Habla Espa&#241;ol
                                                </td>
                                            </tr>
                                        </table>
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                            </table>
                        </div>

                    </td>
                    <td></td>
                </tr>
            </table><!-- /BODY -->

            <!-- FOOTER -->
            <table role="presentation" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
                <tr>
                    <td></td>
                    <td class="container">
                        <!-- content -->
                        <div class="content">
                            <table role="presentation" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" style="width: 100%;">
                                <tr>
                                    <td align="center" style="padding-top: 45px; padding-left: 15px; padding-right: 15px;">
                                            <a href="#" style="text-decoration: none;"><img src="http://hosting-source.bm23.com/35348/public/Pictures/2020_Abandoned_Cart_Images/instagram.png" alt="instagram" style="padding: 1px; margin: 15px; width: 30px; height: 30px; display: inline-block;" /></a>
                                            <a href="#" style="text-decoration: none;"><img src="http://hosting-source.bm23.com/35348/public/Pictures/2020_Abandoned_Cart_Images/facebook.png" alt="facebook" style="padding: 1px; margin: 15px; width: 15px; height: 30px; display: inline-block;" /></a>
                                            <a href="#" style="text-decoration: none;"><img src="http://hosting-source.bm23.com/35348/public/Pictures/2020_Abandoned_Cart_Images/twitter.png" alt="twitter" style="padding: 1px; margin: 15px; width: 30px; height: 24px; display: inline-block;" /></a>
                                            <a href="#" style="text-decoration: none;"><img src="http://hosting-source.bm23.com/35348/public/Pictures/2020_Abandoned_Cart_Images/youtube.png" alt="youtube" style="padding: 1px; margin: 15px; width: 30px; height: 22px; display: inline-block;" /></a>
                                    </td>
                                </tr>

                                <tr>
                                    <td align="center" style="padding-left: 15px; padding-right: 15px; font-weight: bold; font-size: 14px;">
                                        Download our mobile app
                                    </td>
                                </tr>

                                <tr>
                                    <td align="center" style="padding-left: 15px; padding-right: 15px; padding-top: 15px; padding-bottom: 15px;">
                                        <a href="#" style="text-decoration: none;">
                                            <img src="http://hosting-source.bm23.com/35348/public/Pictures/2020_Abandoned_Cart_Images/appstore.png" alt="appstore" style="padding: 1px; width: 140px; display: inline-block;" />
                                        </a>
                                        <a href="#" style="text-decoration: none;">
                                            <img src="http://hosting-source.bm23.com/35348/public/Pictures/2020_Abandoned_Cart_Images/googleplay.png" alt="google play" style="padding: 1px; width: 140px; display: inline-block;" />
                                        </a>
                                        <hr style="margin-top: 45px; margin-bottom: 0px; width: 60%; margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto;">
                                    </td>
                                </tr>

                            </table>
                        </div><!-- /content -->     
                    </td>
                    <td></td>
                </tr>
            </table><!-- /FOOTER -->
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
<!--[if mso]>
 </td></tr></table>
 </center>
<![endif]--> 
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Several things...

Outlook desktops do not support background images https://www.caniemail.com/search/?s=background-image so what is probably happening is that it is taking the 600 width and adding the padding.

You will want to therefore probably (easiest) make the image and text an image. Alternatively, if you can manage it, research background images for Outlook email for the best, most accessible approach. But otherwise, make sure you have the text in the alt tag, i.e. `<img alt="Hurry while stocks last" ... >`

Also, Outlook only respects the attribute width. So make sure you include it, e.g. `<img width="500" ...>` although to make it responsive for others you need to include the width style inline as well, which will override the width attribute, e.g. `<img width="500" style="width:100%;" ..>`

So you have 600 wide picture, but have only given Outlook 580 width. That will push it out too.

Make sure you inline your code. Outlooks generally don't look at embedded CSS - only inline CSS. I.e. don't rely on the code in `<style>...</style>`, instead, use it inline with the code, e.g. `<div class="content" style="...">`. There are online tools that can do it for you.

Finally, when testing, you can cut out a whole section, test it again, and see if that fixes it. This will quickly locate where the problem is.